# How can I verify which class name in the element?

Tags: cypress

I have element. And I need verify which class in this element and do something after that. How can I do it?

```
cy.get('element')
  .should('have.class', 'Enabled')
  .log('Enabled')
  or
  .log('Disabled')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `.then()` function to yield the element found by `cy.get()`, and then using the JQuery function `hasClass` to determine if the yielded element has the `Enabled` class should work.

```js
cy.get('element').then(($el) => {
  cy.log($el.hasClass('Enabled') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled');
  if ($el.hasClass('Enabled')) {
    // some code
  } else {
    // some other code
  }
})
```